# How to get rid of mosquitoes in the garden?

Tags: pests, mosquito

We have a modest garden, about 90 sq.m, with a large, shady tree in the corner. Of late, we've noticed a lot of insects emanating from that corner, particularly some nasty mosquitoes that hang around at all hours of day and night, and make it very unpleasant to sit outside. It may have something to do with the damp soil in that area; we have drip irrigation throughout the garden, but only that corner is permanently shaded from the hot Israeli sun.

What can we reasonably do get rid of the mosquitoes? Bonus if we can get rid of the flies too, but at least they don't bite.

[Video here](https://youtu.be/-Gko7ajpDiY), so you can get a clearer picture.

Comment: Improve ventilation.  Mosquitoes are actually poor fliers and don't hang around where there is a breeze.  Trim the tree to allow more air flow?

Answer (score 2):

You need to eliminate any standing water in the area. That may be problematic (the water may not be on your property), but mosquitoes require water to complete their life cycle, and they don't need much.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @kevinsky answer , a fan is the best way to get rid of them. I use a cheap 24" box fan on low set 20 ft away. A slight breeze will stop them . Removing water is good but what about neighbors and things like bromeliads that hold enough water for a few larva ?